# Pandas conditional group by min()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, min

I am trying to get the minimum value of a date variable when the principal balance is below 5% of the disbursement amount. I want this to be extracted by account number, but I don't want a new df that is grouped by account number.

My df looks like this:

```
| account_number | period_date | principal_balance_amt | disbursement_amt |
| -------------: | ----------- | --------------------- | ---------------- |
| 1              | 2021-01-01  | 10                    | 100              |
| 1              | 2021-02-01  | 6                     | 100              |
| 1              | 2021-03-01  | 3                     | 100              |
| 1              | 2021-04-01  | 0                     | 100              |
| 2              | 2021-01-01  | 20                    | 100              |
| 2              | 2021-02-01  | 15                    | 100              |
| 2              | 2021-03-01  | 11                    | 100              |
| 2              | 2021-04-01  | 8                     | 100              |
```

I have tried codes similar to this to make it work but it just return invalid syntax.

```
df['churn_date'] = df.loc[groupby('account_number').(df['principal_balance_amt'] <= 0.05 * df['disbursement_amt']), 'period_date'].min()
```

I want the code to create a df that looks like this:

| account_number | period_date | principal_balance_amt | disbursement_amt | churn_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 10 | 100 | 2021-03-01 |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 | 6 | 100 | 2021-03-01 |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 | 3 | 100 | 2021-03-01 |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 | 0 | 100 | 2021-03-01 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 20 | 100 | nan |
| 2 | 2021-02-01 | 15 | 100 | nan |
| 2 | 2021-03-01 | 11 | 100 | nan |
| 2 | 2021-04-01 | 8 | 100 | nan |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for replace `period_date` to `NaN` if no match and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `min` for new column:

```
mask = (df['principal_balance_amt'] <= 0.05 * df['disbursement_amt'])
df['churn_date'] = (df.assign(new = df['period_date'].where(mask))
                      .groupby('account_number')['new']
                      .transform('min'))

print (df)
   account_number period_date  principal_balance_amt  disbursement_amt  \
0               1  2021-01-01                     10               100   
1               1  2021-02-01                      6               100   
2               1  2021-03-01                      3               100   
3               1  2021-04-01                      0               100   
4               2  2021-01-01                     20               100   
5               2  2021-02-01                     15               100   
6               2  2021-03-01                     11               100   
7               2  2021-04-01                      8               100   

  churn_date  
0 2021-03-01  
1 2021-03-01  
2 2021-03-01  
3 2021-03-01  
4        NaT  
5        NaT  
6        NaT  
7        NaT
```

Alternative solution with mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) only filtered rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with aggregate `min`:

```
mask = (df['principal_balance_amt'] <= 0.05 * df['disbursement_amt'])
s = df[mask].groupby('account_number')['period_date'].min()

df['churn_date'] = df['account_number'].map(s)
```